# How to set width and height of normal cell view using Caldroid in android?

Tags: android, caldroid

I am using Caldroid library for my project and I am using

```
args.putBoolean(CaldroidFragment.SQUARE_TEXT_VIEW_CELL, false);
```

to use my custom normal cell for month's days.

But when I am trying to set background for a current day, using,

```
if (caldroidFragment != null) {
        caldroidFragment.setBackgroundResourceForDate(R.drawable.current_date,
                minDate);
        caldroidFragment.setTextColorForDate(R.color.purple, minDate);
    }
```

I also try in normal_cell_view.xml

```
android:layout_height="50dp"
```

But it shows like

[image]
How to set it look proper ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you must use not setBackgroundResourceForDate. If you try to setResource - proportions of your drawable will not save. So when you initialize Bundle, change your 
*"setBackground**Resource**ForDate"* 
to 
*"setBackground**Drawable**ForDate"*
:
How it looks in my code in onCreate method:

```
caldroidFragment = new CaldroidFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.your_drawable, null);
caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(drawable, date);
```

*Hope this helps!*

Comment: can you please extend your answer with some useful links or just to make it a bit more informative? To me it seem the code is almost the same as in the question itself... so please, elaborate where was the issue.

Comment: extends a little bit :)